# How do I setup a floating point render targets with libGDX?

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

As OpenGL  2.0 doesn't supports the following extensions:

```
glClampColorARB(GL_CLAMP_VERTEX_COLOR_ARB, GL_FALSE);
glClampColorARB(GL_CLAMP_READ_COLOR_ARB, GL_FALSE);
glClampColorARB(GL_CLAMP_FRAGMENT_COLOR_ARB, GL_FALSE);
```

I need to setup floating point render targets, so that my final texture isn't clamped between 0 and 1. according to the need the texture output unclamped cause i use libGDX for image processing.

trying now for days to get this to work:

```
    frameBuffer1 = new FrameBuffer(usedFormat, w, h, true); 
    frameBuffer2 = new FrameBuffer(usedFormat, w, h, true); 

    frameBuffer1.begin();
    gl20.glViewport(0, 0, frameBuffer1.getWidth(), frameBuffer1.getHeight());
    gl20.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
    gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl20.glActiveTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    testTexture.bind(); //input image texture
    gl20.glEnable(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    meshShader1.begin();
    meshShader1.setUniformi("s_texture", 0);
    mesh.render(meshShader1, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES);
    meshShader1.end();
    frameBuffer1.end(); 

    frameBuffer2.begin();
    gl20.glViewport(0, 0, frameBuffer2.getWidth(), frameBuffer2.getHeight());
    gl20.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
    gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    frameBuffer1.getColorBufferTexture().bind()
    meshShader2.begin();
    meshShader2.setUniformi("s_texture", 0);
    mesh.render(meshShader2, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES);
    meshShader2.end();     
    frameBuffer2.end();
```

I have 2 simple shader programs to test if the texture saves unclamped values. The first subtracts 0.5 from the input texture image and the second one adds 0.5 to the output of the first frame buffer output.